# How to export the current tab (with every window in it) with TOhtml without them being part of diffs?

Tags: vimdiff

I know that when doing a diff, and issuing `TOhtml`, it will export the entire tab into HTML. How can one do the same without those windows in the tab not being diffed?

`:help TOhtml` shows all the options available, but I couldn't find anything that would solve my problem. Did I overlook something?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, `TOhtml` was initially just meant to export a single window. That diff functionality was later added, but this was just a special case. Exporting Tabs is I believe not possible

Comment: I was afraid that this may be the case, but was hoping for a miracle... Thanks!